# navier stokes equation with no boundary condition

Tags: navier-stokes

if we may consider the unsteady motion of flat plate in infinite fluid and make Navier stoke equation into one-dimensional heat equation can we use only initial condition and one derivative condition to solve this equation without boundary values?

Comment: The boundary condition at infinity is zero velocity.